# Is it possible to ignore the link under the image with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML (simplified) and CSS:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  z-index: 0;
}

#plate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333" />
    <img id="plate" src="https://placehold.it/100/999999" />
  </a>

</div>
```

The result can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fcsyrz2h/

How to change the CSS code so that `id="plate"` rectangle is not clickable (so that we don't go to the `href` of `<a>`).

PS. The rest area of `<a>` other than the `<img id="plate">` should be clickable.

P.P.S The question improved.

Comment: you want a hole?

Comment: @Temani Afif, sorry, a hole - what do you mean?

Comment: You could put an after pseudo element on the div over the img, tho it feels a bit hacky.

Comment: a see through thing, like we cut the part of the plate so it's no more visible

Comment: I think there is no pure css solution to prevent a specific child element from being clickable within a link without affecting the clickability of other parts of the link. So you either change the html layout or use a js.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation overlaying with a pseudo after element on thd div does work but I hadn't put it as a solution as it seemed rather hacky. You'd need to know eactly where to put ir.

Answer (score 2):

If you move the second `id="plate"` image that you don't want to be clickable outside of the anchor tag, it should work.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  z-index: 0;
}
#plate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333" />
  </a>
  <img id="plate" src="https://placehold.it/100/999999" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not a css solution, as asked.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to achieve this effect via CSS presentation.

But it is a category of problem which can only be achieved via HTML structure.

**i.e.** you need to think about structure and about which elements should be parents, which should be children and which should be siblings.

---

> How to change the CSS code so that id="plate" rectangle is not clickable (so that we don't go to the href of ).
> [...] The rest area of `<a>` other than the `<img id="plate">` should be clickable.

You can punch a hole in the `<a>` element.

But if you do, then `#plate` will no longer be there.

Because `#plate` is a child of the `<a>` - and you've just punched a `#plate`-sized hole right out of the `<a>`.

---

**Example:**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#plate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  clip-path: path('M 0 0 L 0 204 L 204 204 L 204 0 L 0 0 M 22 32 L 122 32 L 122 132 L 22 132 L 22 32 Z');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://example.com/">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333" />
    <img id="plate" src="https://placehold.it/100/999999" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know enough about the sizing and positioning you can overlay the plate with a transparent after element on the parent div.

So, we can implement the required result on the code given in the question like this:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
}

img {
  z-index: 0;
}

#plate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333" />
    <img id="plate" src="https://placehold.it/100/999999" />
  </a>

</div>
```

Note however how much we've needed to know in advance - positioning, size - so this may not be helpful in the real life situation (the code given was describes as simplified).

Answer (score 0):

> overlaying with a pseudo after element on thd div does work but I hadn't put it as a solution as it seemed rather hacky. You'd need to know eactly where to put ir.

Adjust the pseudo-element to match the dynamic position of the `#plate` image.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  z-index: 0;
}
#plate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0.7;
} 
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:  20px; /* Position to cover the #plate image */
  top:  30px; /* Position to cover the #plate image */
  width:  100px; /* Width of the #plate image */
  height:  100px; /* Height of the #plate image */
  background: transparent; /* Transparent background */
  z-index:  15; /* Higher than #plate but lower than the rest of the content */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/333333"/>
    <img id="plate" src="https://placehold.it/100/999999"/>
  </a>
</div>
```